# Cancel airline reservation on hold

Tags: airlines, bookings, cancellations

I was planning a trip through [Aerosvit Airlines](http://www.aerosvit.ua/eng/index.html). Since I was unsure of my final itinerary and the cost for the particular flight (using sites like [Kayak](http://kayak.com/)) looked like it was about to skyrocket in price, I put the reservation on "hold" through Aerosvit Airlines's website.

Now I want to cancel the reservation, but the booking page doesn't seem to have that option. I know the reservation will expire after a certain amount of time if I don't pay for it, but is there a way to actually cancel the reservation?

I've never used another airline that allowed "holding" a reservation before, so this concept of pay-later for a plane ticket is new to me.

Comment: Many airlines/agencies allow cancellations of reservations either by a visit to the office, a phone call or email. Automatic options are disliked in the case of cancellation to avoid mistakes which could cause a headache to the customers and agencies/airlines since money is involved.

Comment: On-Hold means the seat is not guaranteed, more like "waiting list", so leaving the reservation as it is without cancellation is enough.. there will be time limit after that it will be automatically cancelled.

Comment: On most airlines "on hold" refers to a booking that is confirmed, but not paid for or ticketed.  In that sense it IS guaranteed, as long as you pay/ticket by the deadline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say you held your ticket "through [Aerosvit Airlines's website](http://www.aerosvit.ua/)".  This website has an [FAQ section](http://www.aerosvit.ua/eng/supportcenter.html).

Question 6 of the FAQ reads, ["May I change or cancel my reservation / e-ticket online?"](http://www.aerosvit.ua/eng/supportcenter/nbooking/faq/p1.html). The answer ends with,

> Presently you can not change or delete Your online bookings in the online mode on Your own.
>
> In case of finding out an error, assumed at booking, immediately report to Online Sales Group: online@aerosvit.com.
>   Changes or refund are made without any fees – if the request about an error is reported within 12 hours of the booking date after the online booking was made.
>   For the rebooking questions please contact Call Center  0 800 509 800, (+38044) 4903490 or the nearest aircompany office.
>
> You can fill in the form "[To rebook or to refuse the electronic ticket](http://www.aerosvit.ua/eng/onlservredir/cancellation.html)".
>
> [Live Chat](http://www.aerosvit.ua/eng/index/new_chat.html) service will allow you to change the details of your electronic airline ticket and, if it is required by the fare rules, to pay in the Internet with credit card.

So I think this is the best way to proceed.

The first question in the FAQ is, "How to book and purchase the tickets online?" The answer includes these instructions:

> If You are not currently willing to pay for the ticket online with card, You can pre-book a flight and pay for it within 72 hours. Option for you - "Pay later". You will also receive notification on your e-mail with details of your trip and information about exact time, when you need to buy your ticket .
>   Advance booking must be completed at least 5 days before departure. The ticket price will remain the same as it was at the booking time.

That implies pretty strongly to me that if you do nothing, the airline will drop your reservation, and you will not be charged.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I looked through the FAQs but must have missed the info. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can safely ignore a (On-Hold) reservation as the system will automatically cancel it by the payment deadline. But I strongly advice you to **call the cancellation number for the airlines** to cancel it especially if you have submitted your credit card information. You never know -- they may have some policy of auto-payment by the deadline unless you cancel it manually or even a fine.

Answer (score -2):

The strange thing here is that KAYAK is not even a travel agency! It's just a search engine website so holding the price might actually be a false advertising by I can't claim that by any means however I just doubt it. As an agency or an airlines who have access to a Computer Reservation System that actually have real access to the flight inventory they can't sell it as a Wait List because most Reservations Systems won't be able to price a Wait Listed seat . However I'm sure that airlines won't or the agency won't charge KAYAK for not notifying them that customer no wish to hold the seat but if KAYAK have your credit card information it might charge you for a fee as a profit to the company/website so what I advise you to do is to go to their feedback page and send them an email asking to cancel the itinerary and also to advise about the proper way to cancel an on-hold reservation in the future.

Comment: Actually I meant that I put the reservation on hold through Aerosvit Airlines's website, and that I just checked various prices from competitors from Kayak. I clarified my question.

Comment: AFAIK, Kayak has recently started selling tickets directly for certain airlines too.

Comment: Can confirm @AnkurBanerjee - I actually had a conversation with the guys at flightfox about that very fact.  Good move on kayak's part.